# Redirect requests to one subdirectory with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm running a simple app on a shared hosting which is uploaded like this:

```
public_html
|-- foo
|-- bar
|-- baz
|-- myapp
    |-- private_config
    |-- private_uploads
    |-- public
        |-- css
        |-- images
            |-- existing_file.png
        |-- index.php
        |-- .htaccess
    |-- .htaccess
```

I can only control the contents of the "myapp" directory.

I want requests to `https://example.com/myapp/*` to work as if the root was `public_html/myapp/public`.

I've tried the following:

```
# myapp/.htaccess
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
```

```
# myapp/public/.htaccess
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

This works, but it also lets you access the `public` directory from `https://example.com/myapp/public`, which I don't want.

Effectively, I want the intermediate contents of the "myapp" directory to be invisible, as if it only contained the files from its "public" directory.

These URLs should serve corresponding files from `myapp/public/*`:

- `https://example.com/myapp/images/existing_file.png`
- `https://example.com/myapp/images/`
- `https://example.com/myapp/css/`

These URLs should be handled by `myapp/public/index.php`:

- `https://example.com/myapp/public/images/existing_file.png`
- `https://example.com/myapp/images/does_not_exist.png`
- `https://example.com/myapp/private_configs/secret.txt`

Answer (score 0):

> This works, but it also lets you access the public directory from `https://example.com/myapp/public`, which I don't want.

You can have `myapp/public/.htaccess` like this:

```bash
RewriteEngine On

# external redirect rule to remove /public from URLs
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /myapp/public/(\S*)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /myapp/%1 [L,R=302,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Once you verify it is working fine, replace `R=302` to `R=301`. Avoid using `R=301` (Permanent Redirect) while testing your `mod_rewrite` rules.

Comment: Is it possible to not have a redirect? I want to make URLs to /myapp/* get served as if the contents of /myapp/public/* would have been just pasted there.

Comment: That rule you already have and it should work fine. What you don't have is that if someone types `https://example.com/myapp/public/` then `/public/` will not disappear and that's what this redirect rule does.

Comment: I don't want it to disappear, but rather to behave as if it was a non-existing URL. Imagine if you were to replace `myapp/*` with `myapp/public/*`, then `/public/` would not exist.

Comment: So do you want to return 404 not found when someone enters a URL with /public?